# ODE with additional term

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

In an application I encountered the ODE 
$$ \left( x^2-1 \right) \frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d} x^2} f
 ( x ) +x \left( \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x} f (x)  \right) ( 8x^2-7 ) -4 (C+1) f( x ) =0.
$$
 I don't see how I can find any solution analytically. Does anybody here know whether solutions to this function are known or whether there are any solutions that we can write down? Has this particular ODE ever been studied? I am greatful to every comment. In particular, just a few more solution are helpful too, if you cannot identify them all.

Comment: There are even and odd solutions.  The condition $f(-1)=f(1)$ means you want the *even* solution.  The condition $f'(-1)=f'(1)$ then means that $f'(1)=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to apply the [Frobenius method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html) here.  Writing $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ and substituting into your differential equation gives the following:
$$
(x^2-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2} + x(8x^2-7)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_n x^{n-1} - 4(C+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n=0.
$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is
$$
\left(-n(n+6)-4(C+1)\right)a_n +(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}+8(n-2)a_{n-2},
$$
where the $a_{n-2}$ term only appears for $n\ge 3$.  Since this coefficient must vanish for each $n$, you have
$$
a_2 = 2(C+1)a_0
$$
and
$$
a_{n+2}=\frac{\left(n(n+6)+4(C+1)\right)a_n - 8(n-2)a_{n-2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$
for $n\ge 2$ in the *even* solution (which is the one you're interested in).  Now, unlike the Legendre differential equation, this recursion will not *terminate* for any obvious choice of $C$ (other than $C=-1$, as you pointed out).  But we can look, numerically at least, for choices where the terms go to zero.  (If they instead go to a constant, then the power series diverges at $x=1$.)  Doing this gives eigenvalues at approximately $C=1, -1, -2.75, -6.59, -12.55, -20.53, \ldots$.  The eigenvalues converge rapidly to the usual spectrum, $C_l=-l(l+1)-1/2$ for $l\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: An alternate approach, too, might be to expand the solution as a sum over the even Legendre polynomials, since these are evidently the solutions for large $C$.  Some sort of perturbative attack might then suggest itself.

Comment: You do need $\sum a_n$ to converge, or else the radius of convergence of the power series is $\le 1$.  For this recurrence, I believe that the sum converges if and only if $(a_n)\rightarrow 0$.  But you would need to examine the asymptotic behavior for large $n$.

Comment: No, I don't know that for sure.  It's a reasonable guess, though.

Comment: I numerically iterated the recursion out to about $a_{10000}$, looked at this as a function of $C$ (at steps of $0.01$), and noted where it changed sign.